# Passing PHP data to a vue component

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to use a vue3 single file component on a html page rendered by a php backend, using twig templates. Inside the component i would like to use a value passed from the php backend. Let's say its some id, which the component can use to fetch more data from the backends api.

How should i do that? I can pass the php value as a data attribute on the element on which the component mounts (i.e. `<div id="app" data-personid="<?php echo $personId ?>"></div>`). But i don't know how to get to the mountpoint from within my component.

Is this the preferred way of passing data to the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right you can access the dataset property of the mount point element:

```js
const app = createApp(App);

const mountPoint = document.getElementById('app');
app.provide('personId', mountPoint.dataset.personid);

...
```

then you can use `inject` to get value in the app

```js
<script>
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const personId = inject('personId')
    return { personId }
  }
}
</script>
```

And yes. I would say that using data attributes to pass data from your PHP backend to a Vue app is a good approach.